# Unable to move a partition

Tags: linux, partition, gparted

I have currently following partitioning scheme, the disk is formatted using gpt.
I want to assign the unallocated space highlighted at the end to sdb2 (boot partition).

[image: Partitioning_Scheme]

From my understanding, I need to move sdb3 to end of the disk to be able to do that but gparted is not giving me an option to move sdb3 to the end. (Please see attached image)

[image: UnableToMove]

Can someone please guide me if I am doing something wrong or if I am missing something to achieve an extension on sdb2 ?

Comment: You have LVM or volumes that take all of one partition. Gparted does not work on LVM volumes. Also why more space in /boot, you are only using 450MB of 1.8GB. And your LVM is very small for an install unless minimal server.

Comment: Thanks for answering, this is a test and I want to perform something similar on a production server, I understand that the production system is not designed properly and has only 512MB in the /boot so it gets filled every time there is a kernel update. I have also found the solution to my question and added the steps in the answer section.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer to my question. So adding here if someone is looks at it in the future.

**Warning: every situation can be different and moving partitions can break your system so always ensure you have a backup in place before proceeding.**

1. The small key sign next to the sda3 is crucial you need to remove that before you can move the partition. To remove it, you need to right click sda3 and click Deactivate.
2. Now if you click sda3 and then click move/resize you should be able to move it to the end of the disk and the unallocated space should be available for sda2 to be expanded.
3. Apply the changes and ignore some warnings, this might also take time as it will move all the data at sda3 to the end of the disk depending on how big the partition is in my case it took about 5mins (make sure you read them, in my instance it was complaining about not being able to tell the kernel of the changes but the system was booted from bootable gparted hence I ignored)
4. Once this was completed I had an ! mark against sda2, to which I had to click on sda2 > Partition > Check and then apply pending operations through green tick mark.
5. Rebooted and was able to boot into my ubuntu and here is the current disk layout.

[image: moved]